# How to generate only one report with protractor and cucumber while tests are sharded?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, reportportal

I'm working with reportportal and i want that reports are generated in **only one** launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works fine for me when i forked the projet and i add automerge after all launches are finished.
https://github.com/Yosraaaa/agent-js-cucumber